# JavaFx Showing popup is not working on client machine

Tags: javafx-8, popupwindow

Following is my code to show popup windows in my JavaFx Desktop Application.

```
public boolean popup(Object parent, ViewModelBase viewModel, AsyncCommand cancelCommand) {

        javafx.scene.layout.Pane root = null;
        try
        {               
            if(!IOC.platformInfo.isPlatformThread())
            {

               return PlatformUtil.runAndWait(()->
                {
                    return popup(parent,viewModel,cancelCommand);
                });
            }


            String name = viewModel.getClass().getSimpleName();
            name = Pattern.compile("(viewModel|Controller)$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                    .matcher(name).replaceAll("View");

            FXMLLoader loader  = new FXMLLoader(com.technoinn.videoprospector.ui.fx.service.WindowService
            .class.getResource(String.format("/fxml/%s.fxml",name))
            , null, new JavaFXBuilderFactory(), new IocControllerFactory());
            if(viewModel instanceof ControllerBase)
            {
                loader.setController(viewModel);
            }
            root = loader.load();            

            if(!(viewModel instanceof ControllerBase))
            {
                Object controller = loader.getController();
                if(controller instanceof ControllerBase)
                {
                    ((ControllerBase)controller).setViewModel(viewModel);
                }
            }




            jfxtras.scene.control.window.Window window = 
                   new jfxtras.scene.control.window.Window(viewModel.getDisplayName());
            window.getContentPane().getChildren().add(root);
            window.setPrefSize(root.getPrefWidth(), root.getPrefHeight());
            window.setMinSize(root.getPrefWidth(), root.getPrefHeight());
            CloseIcon closeIcon = new CloseIcon(window);

            window.getLeftIcons().add(closeIcon); 

            Scene scene = new Scene(window);
           // Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(FxModule.StyleFile);




            Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            stage.setResizable(true);

            stage.setMinWidth(root.getPrefWidth());
            stage.setMinHeight(root.getPrefHeight());

            viewModel.addPropertyChangeListener(ViewModelBase.closeCommand,
            (x)->
            {
                if(x.getNewValue()!=null && x.getNewValue()==Boolean.TRUE)
                {
                    stage.close();
                }
            });

            closeIcon.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

            closeIcon.setOnAction((x)->
            {
                if(cancelCommand!=null)
                    cancelCommand.beginExecution();
                else
                    stage.close();
            }); 
            /*

            stage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent event) -> {
                if(cancelCommand!=null)
                    cancelCommand.beginExecution();
                else
                    stage.close();
            });*/
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.centerOnScreen();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            if(!parentWindows.isEmpty())
            {
                stage.initOwner(parentWindows.peek());
                stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            }
            parentWindows.push(stage);

            stage.showAndWait();
            parentWindows.pop();
        }catch(Exception exp)
        {
            Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE,"Error in popup",exp);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Problem is, popup shows well and in proper size on my machine.(Dev Machine). But size on target client machine is unpredictable. Sometimes it is very small and sometimes it does not even show the content pane of the popup window. Client machine has jRE 1.8_31. Any idea what can be wrong. Client machine size is same as that of my dev machine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are calling next code too soon:

```
     window.setPrefSize(root.getPrefWidth(), root.getPrefHeight());
     window.setMinSize(root.getPrefWidth(), root.getPrefHeight());
```

and

```
     stage.setMinWidth(root.getPrefWidth());
     stage.setMinHeight(root.getPrefHeight());
```

Most layout values are being calculated only after scene is shown. Try to move such code after call to

```
stage.showAndWait();
```